# How can I configure my server to make it into a Virtualization Host?

Tags: virtual-machines, centos6

I have an IBM server running Centos 6.4, I have only one Public IP.

I need to create two virtual servers (a full guest OS running on emulated virtual hardware) in it and point them to two different sites.

How I can do that?

I would like to use apache as webserver.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want two differente vhosts running on the same public IP, or do you need two virtual machines running on the CentOS host?

Comment: I need two virtual machines running on the CentOS

Comment: Since you have 1 Public IP(Reachable from outside) you will have to have 2 local IPs for your Virtual Machines. Depending on services you are going to run on those VMs you will have to forward the traffic accordingly.

Comment: I sense some confusion between the terms "virtual host" (a common web server software term) and "virtual machine" (a full guest OS running on emulated virtual hardware). Which one do you actually want? In the first case, include the name of the web server software you use (e.g. Apache httpd, Lighttpd etc.). In the latter case, include the name of the virtualization technology you want to use (or rephrase question to ask which VT is best suited).

Comment: I mean a virtual machine (a full guest OS running on emulated virtual hardware).

Answer (score 1):

So, you've got a server, running on modern hardware (I assume..), and you want to convert it into a Virtualisation Host.

**Caveats:**

**You'll need to be running on a 64-bit CPU, and have a CPU that allows virtualisation, VT-d extensions or similar.**

As of CentOS 5.4, KVM is natively supported as a mechanism of virtualization.

There's a [great guide on the CentOS website](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/KVM) concerning installing and configuring KVM.

Basically, you install the KVM packages, insert the kernel modules, and then use virsh or virt-manager to create VMs on your server.

You can configure Bridged Tap Networking so that your VMs are effectively directly attached to the NIC on your host server.

Alternatively, you can use Host-Only networking, so that the VMs are directly attached to a virtual interface on the host, and that to the interfaces on the virtual guests.

Then you could configure IPtables on the host to route traffic to the guests' host-only adapters as required.

Once you've got your Virtual Machines installed with the Linux distribution of your choice, you can configure them individually to host whichever websites you choose.